# Texture packer and 2d game sprite sheet creation

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, sprite-sheet, texturepacker

I am currently developing a game using Unity3d , my designer gave me a bunch of images created by `After-Effect` which should display the character animations, 
every animation have it's own pack of sprites,but my game got too slow because of the amount of images to be loaded , so i decided to use texture packer to reduce the amount of images and to create only one sprite sheet with type `multiple` containing all the images of my animation ,but my problem is this :
after creating the sprite sheet the animation start to have a weird behavior and does not animate correctly, images start to overlap and do not animate in the same speed  despite the fact that before, the animation was working fine but heavy on my app .
the animation is done on 30fps

how i created the spritesheet : 
I only imported all my assets for every animation into texture packer and export it into png file with a dimension of:4096x4096

Comment: Did you check SpritePacker tool of Unity3d? I don't know why are you thinking about TexturePacker (paid app) if your Unity3d editor has an excellent tool (besides it's working on the native layer with Unity3d engine and your problems can be solved without headache). Check manual here: https://docs.unity3d.com/550/Documentation/Manual/SpritePacker.html

Answer (score -1):

Try to use Simple Sprite Packer plugin next time, and don't forget to compress your `.png`s.